# gromacs compilation gives undefined reference error

Tags: c, gcc

i would like to use gromacs on my open suse 12.3 platform but am having trouble with it.
when trying to compile an analyzing tool using gmx_template i first got this error:

```
g++  -L/usr/local/gromacs/lib   -o msd msd.o -lmd -lgmx -lfftw3f -lxml2  -lnsl             -lm                                                                                                
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:     /usr/local   /gromacs/lib/libgmx.a(pthreads.c.o): undefined reference to symbol         'pthread_getaffinity_np@@GLIBC_2.3.4'                                                                                                                                                                       
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: note:     'pthread_getaffinity_np@@GLIBC_2.3.4' is defined in DSO /lib64/libpthread.so.0 so try     adding it to the linker command     line                                                                                                                                                         
/lib64/libpthread.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid     operation                                                                                                                 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit     status                                                                                                                                        
make: *** [msd] Fehler 1
```

then i added 
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0 to the -L options in the makefile

but now i get a lot of errors like this:

```
/usr/local/gromacs/lib/libgmx.a(pbc.c.o): In function `put_atoms_in_box_omp._omp_fn.0':
pbc.c:(.text+0x862f): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
```

i think they are all related to openmp. i do not understand enough of the building process
to enable openmp support (probably -fopenmp) and am at the same time surprised in case
i would have to change the cmake files in order to make gromacs work. i used the quick and dirty install following the gromacs installation instructions on their website.

any suggestions what i can do / did wrong so far ?
i am using gcc 4.7

Comment: Rather than adding `-L/lib64/libpthread.so.0`, it would probably be better to add `-pthread` to `CFLAGS`, which arranges for any required extra compiler, assembler, and/or linker options required to the respective phases. Don't know if that will completely fix your situation, though, so I'm only putting this as a comment for now...

Comment: ok thank you i will try. it seems unusual i have to do something at all, could this be a sign something is wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: -pthread has been in CFLAGS the whole time!

Comment: Another possibility (based on your first error message - `/lib64/libpthread.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation`) is that your `/lib/libpthread.so.0` has somehow gotten corrupted... I've never seen that specific error before...

Comment: ok how could i try to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my gromacs-2018.4 installation process.

1. pre-installed packages

   - gcc-8.3.0
   - cmake-3.14.1
   - fftw-3.3.8

     ```
     ./configure --prefix=/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/fftw-3.3.8/single_nompi/ --enable-sse2 --enable-avx --enable-float --enable-shared
     ```
2. install gromacs

   ```
   export PATH=/histor/kang/yangpc//soft/09.system/cmake-3.14.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/:/histor/kang/yangpc//soft/lib/packages/gcc-8.3.0/bin/:$PATH
   export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/fftw-3.3.8/single_nompi/:/histor/kang/yangpc//soft/lib/packages/gcc-8.3.0/"
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-8.3.0/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
   unset LIBRARY_PATH CPATH C_INCLUDE_PATH PKG_CONFIG_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH INCLUD
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gmp-5.1.3/lib/:/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/mpc-1.0.1/lib/:/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/mpfr-4.0.1/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ~/soft/09.system/cmake-3.14.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/13.DrugDesign/GROMACS/gromacs-2018.4/InstallPos/ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-8.3.0/bin/gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-8.3.0/bin/g++"
   make
   make install
   ```